# How to return HTTP response with file content and also re-render page

Tags: django

I have simple page with one view that displays a form. When the 'submit' for the form is clicked, a file is downloaded in the browser. Here's what the code for my view looks like (I've stripped out much of the unrelated code to help highlight what I'm trying to ask):

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

# My custom form
from .forms import CalendarForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = CalendarForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid
        if form.is_valid():
            # Fetch the form data here, and generate test.pdf
            # file based on form data (code removed for brevity)

            # Build HTTP request containing contents of static file to download
            with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as fh:
                resp = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
                resp['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment;filename=test.pdf')

            # Return HTML response containing file contents: I also
            # want to re-render the calendar.html page here but don't know how
            return resp
        else:
            # Do error stuff (code removed for brevity)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = CalendarForm()

    # Re-render the page
    return render(request, 'calendar.html', {'form': form})
```

In the case where a response containing the file contents is returned, I would also like to re-load the calendar.html page, just like the very last return statement of get_name does. I'm not experienced in web development, so I'm sure there's a design pattern or something here that I'm missing.

What would be the correct way to arrange things here so that submitting a correct form would result in the file being downloaded, *and* the calendar.html page being reloaded?

Comment: Why don't you just put a link to the PDF in your calendar.html?

Comment: it's not actually static, there's a bunch of code in there to generate a PDF based on the form data. I took that out for the post cause I thought it would just obscure the important bits

Comment: Have added a comment in the code sample to clarify this

Comment: Hmm, I think there might be some more elegant solution, but what I can advise - cache the content of that pdf file, render calendar.html  normally (with some info about that file cached) and then make AJAX request and download that file from cache.